# Question on basic vector operations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $u = (1,2,3) , v = (2,3,4)$
a) Find $2u-3v$
b) Find $\|u\|$.
c) Find a constant $c$ such that $u$ is perpendicular to $u + cv$.

I figured out part a, I am just struggling with b) and c). If anyone can help me or give me some insight with these questions that would be great. 
Thank you in advance, Matt.

Comment: Please show your work or attempts.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the definition of a norm, part b) follows almost immediately. As a reminder,

$$\lvert \lvert u \rvert \rvert = \sqrt{u \cdot u}$$

Where $u \cdot u$ is the standard dot product.

For c), you must know that two vectors are perpendicular iff their dot product is $0$. So in this case, you must find the $c$ such that:

$$u \cdot (u + cv) = u \cdot u + u \cdot cv = ||u||^2 + c(u \cdot v) = 0$$
Where the above relations follow from the linearity of the dot product. Thus,
$$c = -\frac{||u||^2}{u \cdot v}$$
**note:** This formula only holds if $u \cdot v \ne 0$. In other words, when $u$ and $v$ are *already* perpendicular, in which case it should be obvious that $c = 1$ works.

Answer (score 0):

For (b), $\|u\|$ is the distance from origin to a point with position vector $u$. Can you apply Pythagoras' theorem on this?

For (c), vectors $a,b$ are perpendicular if $a\cdot b=0$. Can you applying this to you problem?